# Call javascript from server side on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
var r = {  
        init : function(){  
             r = Raphael("pie");
            //r.g.txtattr.font = "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif";
            r.g.text(320, -330, "Message Status").attr({ "font-size": 20 });

            var pie = r.g.piechart(360, -180, 100,  <%= Session["uStats"] %>, { legend: [<%= Session["vkeyColor"] %>], colors: [<%= Session["vPieColor"] %>]  });
            pie.hover(function () {
                this.sector.stop();
                this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);
                if (this.label) {
                    this.label[0].stop();
                    this.label[0].scale(1.5);
                    this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
                }
            }, function () {
                this.sector.animate({ scale: [1, 1, this.cx, this.cy] }, 500, "bounce");
                if (this.label) {
                    this.label[0].animate({ scale: 1 }, 500, "bounce");
                    this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
                }
            });
            var r = Raphael("pie"),

                    data2 = [<%= Session["vProgressPercentage"] %>];
                    axisx = ["10%", "20%"];
            r.g.txtattr.font = "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif";
             r.g.barchart(80, 25, 100, 320, data2, { stacked: true, colors: [<%= Session["vProgressColor"] %>,'#fff'] });
             axis2 = r.g.axis(94, 325, 280, 0, 100, 10, 1);
        }
        }
          window.onload = function () {
          r.init();
        };
```

The Javascript is executed when the page loads, I do partial postback using a update panel, the javascript is not executed during post back how to call it from server side.

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="smCharts" runat="server" />
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
             Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
             function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                 r.init();
             }
             function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                 r.init();
             }

            </script>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Holder" OnLoad="messsagePercentStats" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div id="pie" onclick="__doPostBack('Holder', '');" style="top: -125px; left: -20px; width: 610px; position: relative;
                    height: 389px;">
                </div>
```

This is what I am trying and the graph is not changed. it remains constant as in page load

```
protected void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        String MsgID = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["MsgID"];
        int msgID = Convert.ToInt32(MsgID);
        BindGridViewUsers(msgID);

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "loadpie", "r.init();");
        Holder.Update();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to call a javascript function from an update panel; something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"key","javscriptfunction();" , false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put this script inside a function:

```
function foo() {
    ...
}
```

which will be executed upon DOM load:

```
window.onload = function () {
    foo();
};
```

and upon server side postback from an UpdatePanel:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "foo", "foo();", true);
```

Comment: I have updated the code, can you say me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` does not work after the page has already loaded. Use

`$(function(){ r.init();})`

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('I'm an alert');</script>");
```

Just put your code  in instead of the `alert`. You might be able to call the function from there, but I haven't tested that.